# Kotlin, app storage: Need to store an ArrayList of Integers from user interaction

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, integer, storage

I am building an app as part of a project and I am stuck at the moment.

Background: My team is making a "Time-Wasting" App, and the user can press buttons such as "study" to track their time spent on activities - so there will be lots of integers values in the growing ArrayList.

Task:
Store a growing Arraylist(integers) in the app store and retrieve the values for calculation and graph display purposes.

Problem:
I have looked so far how do to this, but I am a bit stuck. Do I use SharedPreferences, the internal app storage or something else. Also, I have a hard time finding code that I could look at and follow what it is doing.

I need:
An efficient way to store the ArrayList (integers) in a storage place and retrieve it for my app. Any suggestions what would be best and where would I find the code for that?

I looked for about 2 weeks through videos and a through stack overflow but I am still stuck and not closer to how I should store this data type in my app.

Thanks, any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion avoid the array list and use a database.
It will allow your app to grow including storing extra information along with the time waster including when they chose to do it, how long , etc.
I recommend Room Database it is an ORM for Sqlite it is super easy to use and there is plenty of documentation on implementation as it's apart of the Android Jet Pack.

If you are really stuck on using a list you can use SharedPreferences it doesn't handle ordered lists but you can store your list as a json string.